# accessing session from the web middleware to the api middleware in laravel 5.3

Tags: ajax, session, laravel-5.3

I want to set a session in the server and have it available anytime. I'm using Laravel 5.3, I have the following code on one of my controllers:

```
Session::set('csrf_token', str_random(72));
return view('index', [
    'session' => $session,
    'csrf_token' => Session::get('csrf_token')
]);
```

then I made an Ajax request using a package called `axios`

```
axios.post('to-that-route', 'some-data')
     .then(response => console.log(response))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

My problem is with the controller that handle this ajax request, it seems that it doesn't know the session that I just set, in fact this:

```
return response()->json(var_dump(Session::get('csrf_token')));
```

would give me `null`, that means it doesn't know about the `session csrf_token`. How do I handle this?

EDIT:

I tried doing this:

```
public function handler(Request $request) {
    // set the session
    $request->session()->put('csrf_token', str_rand(72));
}


// the controller that handles the ajax request
public function handler(Request $request) {
    return response()->json(var_dump($request->session->get('csrf_token')));
}
```

it gave me an error saying `Session store not set on request.`

EDIT:

Sorry about this, I wasn't looking closely, the reason is because the session was set on the `web.php` which is under `web middleware`, and the controller that handles the ajax request is in the `api.php` is under the `api middleware`.

So I would like to revise the question, is there a way to access the session from the `web middleware` to the `api middleware`?

Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Just to be clear is the purely to get the `csrf_token` to vue?

Comment: Nope, it is to get the value of the session that was set.

Comment: also I am not using **vue** I am using **react** but that doesn't seem to be of any importance since the issue here is laravel.

Comment: I just assumed as vue comes out of the box. My bad!

Comment: It's okay, I figured out what was wrong on the first issue, I wasn't thinking closely, can you answer the follow up question?

Comment: It might be worth putting it in an answer incase anyone else has the same issue and comes looking :)

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about this, I wasn't looking closely, the reason is because the session was set on the web.php which is under web middleware, and the controller that handles the ajax request is in the api.php is under the api middleware.

So I would like to revise the question, is there a way to access the session from the web middleware to the api middleware?

Sorry, my bad.